# How can I export all contents to my local drive from cloudinary?

Tags: cloudinary

Is there any method to download all contents in cloudinary as one zip file or download all contents using any plugin.

I have multiple folders and subfolders containing images in Cloudinary.

Answer (score 0):

Bulk downloading images from your Cloudinary account can currently be done in the following ways:

1. Using the [Admin API](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/admin_api). Listing all resources and extracting their URLs for download.
2. Download as a zip file using the [ZIP generation API](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#generate_archive)
3. Backup to a private S3 bucket. Please see - http://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/203744391-How-do-I-grant-Cloudinary-with-the-permissions-to-backup-on-my-private-S3-bucket-